# Warning: ....SettingWithCopyWarning don't understand

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6

Hello,

I have problem with my code Python 3. I want to copy tupple in a cell dataframe. Python return warning message ...SettingWithCopyWarning...

```
data={'Debut': ['19/12/2016','18/1/2017','13/2/2017','10/3/2017']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Début'],index=['P1','P2','P3','P4'])
d=data['Début'][0]
d=d.split("/")
d.reverse()
d= tuple(list(map(int,d)))
df.Début[i]=d
```

I read pandas doc. and I try this... but python return error...(Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable).

```
df.loc[0,'Début']=d
```

other way ...no work,it's  same error.

```
df.at[0,'Début']=d
```

Comment: It’s because df and d are both pointing to the same data object. If you make a change to d you will change df. You can copy df with .copy() if that is going to be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out, there is an issue that your dataframe is already using a copy of the data dictionary as it's data, and so there are issues with copied data. One way you can avoid this by processing your data in the way you want it before you put it in the dataframe. For instance:

```
import pandas as pd

data={'Debut': ['19/12/2016','18/1/2017','13/2/2017','10/3/2017']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Début'], index = ['P1','P2','P3','P4'])
# Split your data, make a tuple out of it, and reverse it in a list iteration
date_tuples = [tuple(map(int, i.split("/")))[::-1] for i in data['Debut']]
df['Début'] = date_tuples
```

Comment: ### Cool  Thk !!